# K8s ingress for path based routing for multiple services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using nginx ingress for path based routing for multiple services .

My services output

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      

ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   X.X.X.33    X.X.X.112   80:30853/TCP,443:31386/TCP   
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      X.X.X.139   <none>           443/TCP                      

test1                         ClusterIP      X.X.X.197   <none>           9080/TCP                     
test2                         ClusterIP      X.X.X.30    <none>           9995/TCP
```

My ingress.yaml file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test2
        backend:
          serviceName: test2
          servicePort: 9995
      - path: /test1
        backend:
          serviceName: test1
          servicePort: 9080
```

and kubectl ingress output

```
NAME               HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress-resource   *                 80      45m
```

When i am trying to access service from outside cluster -
I am getting 404

```
-> http:// X.X.X.112/test1 return 404
-> http:// X.X.X.112/test2 return 404 

Where  X.X.X.112 is external ip of ingress-nginx-controller
```

-> When I create ingress to services running on port 8080, it seems to be working fine.
What the issue ?

Comment: can you get endpoint for those 2 services? please add output ```kubectl get ep``` to description so that we cam get idea

Comment: ingress-nginx-controller             X.X.X.90:80,X.X.X.90:443    \n
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   X.X.158.90:8443           \n
test1                                X.X.159.92:9080            \n
test2                                X.X.155.153:9995

Comment: 404 is the default answer to paths that are not found. I assume the corresponding paths are not even hit. The easiest to debug this is to look in config files of nginx at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and `/etc/nginx/conf.d/whatever` and looking at the logs output `kubectl logs --tail=20 --follow name-of-your-nginx-pod`.

Comment: Where is you Cluster deployed (Locally, Azure, AWS, GCP)? With an Cloud Loadbalancer?

Comment: GCP . Catch is any service running on port 8080 seems to be working fine with path based routing.

Comment: To be more clear. I am trying to do -  echo "{somejson}" | curl -d @- http://// X.X.X.112/test1/save/ --header "Content-Type: application/json" ................................if I try the same thing using service clusterIP from other pods, test1 service is working fine.

Comment: Can you provide an output from the logs? Or the nginx configuration? It would help a lot. It is clearly failing to find the path somewhere. The question is where. The configuration looks good, so maybe the port mapping on the containers doesn't work right?

Comment: @pythonhmmm you are using `Google Kubernetes Engine` or `Google Compute Engine` and `Kubeadm`/`Minikube`? If you are using `GKE`, you need to force using `Nginx Ingress` as default GCP Ingress is not supporting `rewrite`. Please clarify what you want to achieve (`GCP Ingress` or `Nginx Ingress`) and add additional `Deployment` and `Service` YAMLs. If you will point to different port than app is listening you will also get 404.

Comment: As I suggested you added annotation to force `nginx` on GKE. Add services YAMLs and information on what ports your application is listening. It would be great if you could provide your YAMLs to verify whole configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was missing

```
annotations:
 kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

Now I have other issue.
When I use

```
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: test2
          servicePort: 9995
```

My http:// X.X.X.112/ works fine and it points to serviceName - test2
Similarly it works for other service.

but when I use

```
  spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test2
        backend:
          serviceName: test2
          servicePort: 9995
      - path: /test1
        backend:
          serviceName: test1
          servicePort: 9080
```

and I get  405 method  not allowed, when doing

```
 -> http:// X.X.X.112/test1 return 405
-> http:// X.X.X.112/test2 return 405
```

I tired adding few more annotations .

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
```

I am missing something else ?

Comment: Instead providing an answer you should edit your question.

Comment: This is not the answer, again question!

Answer (score 0):

Ive tried your example on GKE (with changed deployment as you didnt provide which one you have used).

As I mentioned in comments, to force `Nginx Ingress` on `GKE` you must use annotation:

```
annotations: 
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

Otherwise GKE will use default `gce` ingress which do not support [rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) annotation.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: test1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        key: test1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello1
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test1
spec:
  selector:
    key: test1
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind:  Deployment
metadata:
  name: test2
  labels:
    app: mycha-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx2
          image: nginx
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test2
  labels:
    app: test2
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: test2
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test1
        backend:
          serviceName: test1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /test2
        backend:
          serviceName: test2
          servicePort: 80
      
$ kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
default         kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.0.0.1      <none>          443/TCP                      7h59m
default         test1                                ClusterIP      10.0.14.220   <none>          80/TCP                       9m18s
default         test2                                ClusterIP      10.0.0.243    <none>          80/TCP                       9m16s
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.7.75     35.228.2XX.XX   80:32643/TCP,443:32733/TCP   18m

$ curl 35.228.2XX.XX/test1
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: test1-5844dc9688-n95tj
$ curl 35.228.2XX.XX/test2
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
...
```

If this example **will not work on your cluster**, you will need to create [Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) to allow traffic.

If this example **will work** it means that you have configuration mismatch in your `Deployment/Service`.

- It might be [selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) misconfigure between `service` and `deployment` (in first one it was `key: test1` and in second deployment `app: test2`).
- Application is listening on different port that was set in `containerPort`. If you set only `port` in service, the same value will be set in `containerPort`. In `test1` deployment it would not work as `hello-app:1.0` listening only on `port 8080`.

**Hello pod**

```
# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/hello-app
```

**Nginx pod**

```
# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
```

Please comment if you will still have issue.

Comment: Thanks, your example works, But  I have issue with following - when I try to do ''''' curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"emailId":"abc@abc.com"}' http://<Ingress_ip/save'''''  ( It works for "/" and for other "/test2" I get 405 error.  Similarly When I reverse ( "/test1" I get 405 and for other "/" it works )

Comment: Could you provide your SVC, Deployment YAMLs to the question. What GKE version are you using. Did you configured firewall to allow traffic to your application ports?